# Swift - iOS : unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift

I'm developing a UIViewController with 2 TableView, following Swift specification I created a class with UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource interfaces for managing TableViews.

```
    class CurrencyController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
 var valute = [NSManagedObject]()
 var categoria = [NSManagedObject]()


  //....
}
```

I wrote the func to support rearranging TableView:

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if tableView == self.tabCurrency{
        //
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("currencyRow", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CurrencyCell

        let thisElem = valute[indexPath.row]

        cell.curName.text = thisElem.valueForKey("valuta") as! String?  //This code generates the exception
        let elem = thisElem.valueForKey("cambio") as! Double? //This code generates the exception

        cell.rateCur.text = "\(elem!)"
        return cell
    }else{
        //
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("categoryRow", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CategoryCell

        let thisElem = categoria[indexPath.row]

        cell.catName.text = thisElem.valueForKey("cat_name") as! String? //This code generates the exception
        return cell
    }

}
```

This code generates *unexepctedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value* but using the PO command I saw that variable didn't contain nil values...

Any idea? Thank you in advance

**UPDATE**: 
I wrote the declaration of "valute" and "categoria" objects.

Comment: what type is `thisElem`?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't write the type of thisElem. thisElem type is NSManagedObject

Comment: Doesn't the compiler complain about `as! String?`. It's either `as! String` forced casted or `as? String` optional bound, but no trailing question mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I saw what I did wrong: I didn't link my CategoryCell and CurrencyCell classes with the Prototype Cell in the Storyboard.

CategoryCell and CurrencyCell are my classes that extend UITableViewCell in order to manage all cells of tho TableView.

Now I link these classes with storyboard properly and now it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

It seems:

```
this.valueForKey("cambio")
```

should be:

```
thisElem.valueForKey("cambio").
```

`this` -> `thisElem`

Comment: no thisElem is correct, thisElem represents the selected element from NSManagedObject array linked to TableView

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I didn't see my mistake :-D... I'm ashamed .. I'm going to update my code. Anyway I resolve my issues, thank you for the tip